# Super-Villain's Super "Riddle"

Tags: riddle, knowledge

We are four entities fear us all,
We are the most feared above them all.
Below is our spoken message, prepare your fall,
Mixed and scrambled to watch you fall.

---

We are all born into this world through blood and pain,
Faced with the inescapable fact that human existence is mad.
Our roles are nothing more than how the times choose to cast us,
But something good always came out of it in the long run.

We got blood in our veins, murder in our eyes, and time on our hands,
It’s easier than explaining what’s killing you inside.
Scars are far more vivid reminders than memories,
As it is, nothing but cold empty contempt.

It’s the inevitable horrid truth of everything:
Everything goes to die.
One bad day to reduce the sanest man,
In suffocation of all that you hold dear.

There are no heroes or villains,
We can choose to be good or bad.
But, I don’t kill humans out of hate. I kill them out of love.
So, I'll slaughter every damn one of you.

---

Hint:

> Three of these villains share the same universe, in a way. Some of them have all met with each other one way or another, but very rarely, and most likely won't for a while. It wasn't for a cup of coffee, that I assure you. The answer is also 100% objective, and there is absolutely no way to argue the objectivity. If your answer feels like a guess, that's probably because it is, and thus, wrong.

Hint #2:

> The lines... they're very specific... sources.

Comment: For like a semi-hint. Don't overthink it. The prolouge at the top is also a hint for the riddle. Finally, this is a semi-riddle. Partial-riddle. Imposter-riddle. Good luck!

Comment: I'm not (even near) an expert, but this riddle suggest me some kind of **bacteria** or **microorganism**

Comment: Guys, y'all still have to use *textual evidence* to support your claims.

Comment: Also, the answers consist of four actual comic book supervillains, it's not metaphorical. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I (finally) got it.

> These are all quotes from different villains: The Joker, Magneto, Void, and Carnage.
>
>  **The Joker**
>  Faced with the inescapable fact that human existence is mad.
>  One bad day to reduce the sanest man (alive to lunacy)
>  We can choose to be good or bad.
>  It’s easier than explaining what’s killing you inside.
>
> **Magneto**
>  Our roles are nothing more than how the times choose to cast us.
>  There are no heroes or villains.
>  Scars are far more vivid reminders than memories.
>  But I don’t kill humans out of hate. I kill them out of love.
>
>  **Void**
>  But something good always came out of it in the long run.
>  It’s the inevitable horrid truth of everything:
>  Everything goes to die.
>  In suffocation of all that you hold dear.
>
>  **Carnage**
>  As it is, nothing but cold empty contempt.
>  We got blood in our veins, murder in our eyes, and time on our hands.
>  So, I'll slaughter every damn one of you.
>  We are all born into this world through blood and pain.

Comment: Updated with answers!

Comment: Great job! Well done.

Comment: took me way too long, I thought rot13(gurfr jrer yvarf NOBHG gur punenpgref, abg dhbgrf SEBZ gurz.)

Comment: hehe. That was the point :P

Answer (score 7):

Gotta suspect the four rungs of ...

> ... [DNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA):
>  Cytosine (C), guanine (G), adenine (A), thymine (T),

Or their mirrors of ...

> ... [mRNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messenger_RNA), tRNA and rRNA.

These are the ingredients of life as we know it, for better or worse.

Comment: Really good guess, but unfortunately, it is not the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Could the answer be:

> The four types of pathogens - bacteria, viruses, fungi and Protozoa?

After all,

> There are plenty of helpful microorganisms, (not heroes or villains)...

Comment: Good try, but nope!